# cant connect database mysql through tcp forwarding

Tags: mysql, tcp, gcloud, portforwarding

i want to access database in google cloud server via TCP Forwarding, I have `username` = root `password` = my-password , `server-name`

i am doing:

1. Set TCP Forward in cloud server

gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel sg01dbcluster-node-2 3306
--local-host-port=localhost:3307
--zone=asia-southeast1-b

output :

```
Listening on port [3307].
```

2. Then i connect to database server using mysql workbench
   hostname localhost
   port :3307
   username : root
   password : my-password

but i have error:

```
Failed to Connect to MySQL at localhost:3307 with user root    
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

any idea what step that i missed ?

Comment: the mysql database is installed on the instance you are accessing or it is a Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: the database was MongoDB Atlas @breddy

Comment: maybe you do not need the :3307 on --local-host-port flag. Take a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#tunneling_other_tcp_connections)

Comment: @breddy i have done following these tutorial and what should i do in the next ?

Comment: per [this](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/tutorial/connect-bic-workbench/) MongoDB atlas default port should be 27015. Did you change it to use port 3307?

Comment: halo @breddy i have done fixing the problem, thank u

Answer (score 0):

i have done fixing the connecting problem, before that i am sounding that i have a instances-name , username root and password my-password  to connect database in cloud server (the database was sql) via TCP IP forwarding. cloud server was google cloud compute engine.  here are the step:

in local

1. [gcloud config set](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set) (i am using config set project and zone, don't forget using alpha/beta if the code doesn't running)
2. [TCP Other connection](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#tunneling_other_tcp_connections) (check last section)

   gcloud beta compute start-iap-tunnel my-instances-name 3306 --local-host-port=localhost:3309

wait a second until show:

```
Listening Port [3309]
```

3. Open mysql workbench and put the hostname : localhost , port : 3309 , username : root , password : my-password